# Facebook FQL: Post Impressions Not Being Retrieved when filtering by Post Id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the the impressions of a wall post. I was able to get the impressions of all the posts given a source id b y doing this:

```
SELECT post_id,impressions,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id= [source_id]
```

However when I just get the impressions of a post, the api returns nothing:

```
SELECT post_id,impressions,created_time FROM stream WHERE post_id= [post_id]
```

I even tried this variation:

```
SELECT post_id,impressions,created_time FROM stream WHERE post_id= [post_id] AND source_id = [source_id]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited and condensed answer**: are you wrapping `post_id` in single quotes(`'`)?

**Old answer**:

I don't see any issues with this code. My initial thought was that `post_id` wasn't indexable, but [it is](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). One other thought though, are you wrapping `post_id` in single quotes(`'`)?

Per-post impressions is a fairly new feature, perhaps there's a bug. Have you [filed a bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/)?

Comment: Yes post_id is indexable but I was thinking this might be a bug because I have encountered something similar before. According to the documentation, app_id is indexable too but there's actually a bug which doesn't allow you to filter by app_id - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13662

Comment: As to the wrapping of post_id in quotes, I don't think it's an issue I was able to query filtering with the source id without the quotes and it returned a whole list of posts with impressions.

Comment: Yeah, make sure you're wrapping `post_id` in single quotes (as it's not a number, but two numbers concatenated by an `_`; you probably know this, but you know, sanity check), but I'd conclude the same thing as you - it's a bug.

Comment: Definitely try the quotes. It does make a difference.

Comment: Oh actually putting the quotes worked. I just realized that if I were to do this in an actual database it would return an error without the quotes. Yes thanks! :)

Comment: My beef probably right now is that there is no error message!

Comment: Thing is, `post_id`s look like `12352342_23423413`, which is a string. That *might* work in a normal database but it's not guaranteed to. So for future reference, always best to wrap that in single quotes. :)